# Cricket DLS method

Tags: cricket

In DLS method whether the target will  be fixed against balls? Or the target will be fixed for overs? when play interrupted by rain. 
Whether the target will be fixed against breaking an over? OR will be fixed against full overs?

Answer (score 1):

The DLS par score is calculated as so many runs off so many overs.  For example 200 runs in 29 overs.  In almost all matches using DLS there will be an official responsible for the DLS, and the umpires are solely responsible for deciding how many overs have been lost as a result of the delay.

The DLS manager then uses either the computer software or the manual tables to calculate the DLS par score based on the number of overs gone and number of wickets lost.  This is usually provided to the umpires and captains and displayed on the scoreboard.  It is convention on the scoreboard to show the DLS par score at the end of the current over assuming no wickets fall and to adjust the score as soon as a wicket does fall.

I am an umpire in the UK and my match on Saturday was reduced to 41 overs a team, and we thought we might get rain delays in the second innings so we had a DLS chart provided by the scorers from the start of the second innings.

The regulations will usually specify a minimum number of overs that constitutes a match.  These must have been bowled for a side to have won by DLS even if they have passed the par score.

Additionally it should be noted the par score is not the score to win, that is always 1 more than the par.

Answer (score 0):

D/L par score is calculated based upon the number of balls that can be bowled before the end of the Match time considering the moderate rate of Overs per Hour. But the target is always given for a full quota of overs. For example 200 runs in 29 Overs. Not 200 in 29.3 overs. So target is always fixed for full overs.

Although, to enforce a result from D/L a certain number of overs have to be played. like 20 overs in 50 overs and 5 overs in T20 Cricket.